# Swift weak var scenario

Tags: swift, weak-references

I was reading the CoreData docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CoreDataandStoryboards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH10-SW1) and came across the following example illustrating how to implement a segue from a parent list to a child using dependency injection and was a little confused by the code sample given.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {   
    weak var employee: AAAEmployeeMO?   
}
```

and in the `MasterViewController`

```
let CellDetailIdentifier = "CellDetailIdentifier"
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier! {
    case CellDetailIdentifier:
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedObject = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AAAEmployeeMO
        destination.employee = selectedObject
    default:
        print("Unknown segue: \(segue.identifier)")
    }
}
```

I've got a decent understanding of weak variables but am a bit confused with this particular case because I don't see how it is necessary in this scenario.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why it is used here? Where is the potential for a strong reference cycle?